# Mongodb send me incorrect object with different id

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I use express as backend, mongodb and mongoose.
I don't understand why i get from database incorrect object.

In general, i send from frontend post request with id:  6210915b2b72a91fe72d9201.
On backend i reseive that id and want to fetch object with same id from mongodb

This code:

```
router.post('/reaction_on_user', async (req, res) => {


  let womanid = req.body.id 
  console.log(womanid, ' before findOne')
  const womanData = await User.findOne({womanid}).select('_id name age photos')
  console.log(womanid, ' after findOne')
```

In console.log i see id which i send -- 6210915b2b72a91fe72d9201.
But object from database have different id -- 6210915b2b72a91fe72d91f5. This different id was some requests ago.

Answer (score 0):

Oh. Now i wrote:

```
const womanData = await User.findOne({_id: womanid}).select('_id name age photos')
```

and it works...